# Adding images to WOWslider without regenerating the slider

Tags: jquery

Good Day

With regard to the great jQuery plugin : [WOWSlider](http://wowslider.com/)

I want to add images to the slider, but adding them manually in the html file creates issues in Chrome and IE (see attached image)

What do I need to add to the script.js or wowslider.js files (two required js files for the slider) to be able for the slider to work properly in Chrome and IE

Here is my code:

HTML

```
 <div id="wowslider-container1">
               <div class="ws_images">
                        <ul>
                            <li><img src="images/wowslider/wallpaper307776.jpg" alt="wallpaper-307776" title="wallpaper-307776" id="wows1_0"/></li>
                            <li><img src="images/wowslider/wallpaper2538242.jpg" alt="wallpaper-2538242" title="wallpaper-2538242" id="wows1_1"/></li>
                            <li><img src="images/wowslider/wallpaper2624538.jpg" alt="wallpaper-2624538" title="wallpaper-2624538" id="wows1_2"/></li>
  <!--  **********************************************
  I tried to add these two images below manually:
  -->   *****************************************
                            <li><img src="images/wowslider/wallpaper2561740.jpg" alt="wallpaper-2624538" title="wallpaper-2624538" id="wows1_3"/></li>
                            <li><img src="images/wowslider/wallpaper2623792.jpg" alt="wallpaper-2624538" title="wallpaper-2624538" id="wows1_4"/></li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="ws_bullets">
                    <div>
                        <a href="#" title="wallpaper-307776"><img src="images/wowslider/tooltips/wallpaper307776.jpg" alt="wallpaper-307776"/>1</a>
                        <a href="#" title="wallpaper-2538242"><img src="images/wowslider/tooltips/wallpaper2538242.jpg" alt="wallpaper-2538242"/>2</a>
                        <a href="#" title="wallpaper-2624538"><img src="images/wowslider/tooltips/wallpaper2624538.jpg" alt="wallpaper-2624538"/>3</a>
                        <a href="#" title="wallpaper-2624538"><img src="images/wowslider/tooltips/wallpaper2624538.jpg" alt="wallpaper-2624538"/>4</a>
                        <a href="#" title="wallpaper-2624538"><img src="images/wowslider/tooltips/wallpaper2624538.jpg" alt="wallpaper-2624538"/>5</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="ws_shadow"></div>
  </div>
```

JS: wowslider.js file

```
jQuery.fn.wowSlider=function(x){var D=jQuery;var k=this;var h=k.get(0);x=D.extend({effect:function(){this.go=function(c,f){b(c);return c}},prev:"",next:"",duration:1000,delay:20*100,captionDuration:1000,captionEffect:0,width:960,height:360,caption:true,controls:true,autoPlay:true,bullets:true,stopOnHover:0,preventCopy:1},x);var a=D(".ws_images",k);var I=a.find("ul");function b(c){I.css({left:-c+"00%"})}D("<div>").css({width:"100%",visibility:"hidden","font-size":0,"line-height":0}).append(a.find("li:first img:first").clone().css({width:"100%"})).prependTo(a);I.css({position:"absolute",top:0,animation:"none","-moz-animation":"none","-webkit-animation":"none"});var q=x.images&&(new wowsliderPreloader(this,x));var i=a.find("li");var B=i.length;function w(c){return((c||0)+B)%B}var t=navigator.userAgent;if((/MSIE/.test(t)&&parseInt(/MSIE\s+([\d\.]+)/.exec(t)[1],10)<8)||(/Safari/.test(t))){var P=Math.pow(10,Math.ceil(Math.LOG10E*Math.log(B)));I.css({width:P+"00%"});i.css({width:100/P+"%"})}else{I.css({width:B+"00%",display:"table"});i.css({display:"table-cell","float":"none",width:"auto"})}var z=x.onBeforeStep||function(c){return c+1};x.startSlide=w(isNaN(x.startSlide)?z(-1,B):x.startSlide);b(x.startSlide);var F;if(x.preventCopy&&!/iPhone/.test(navigator.platform)){F=D('<div><a href="#" style="display:none;position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%"></a></div>').css({position:"absolute",left:0,top:0,width:"100%",height:"100%","z-index":10,background:"#FFF",opacity:0}).appendTo(k).find("A").get(0)}var g=[];i.each(function(c){var Y=D(">img:first,>a:first,>div:first",this).get(0);var Z=D("<div></div>");for(var f=0;f<this.childNodes.length;){if(this.childNodes[f]!=Y){Z.append(this.childNodes[f])}else{f++}}if(!D(this).data("descr")){D(this).data("descr",Z.html().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,""))}D(this).css({"font-size":0});g[g.length]=D(">a>img",this).get(0)||D(">*",this).get(0)});g=D(g);g.css("visibility","visible");if(typeof x.effect=="string"){x.effect=window["ws_"+x.effect]}var O=new x.effect(x,g,a);var A=x.startSlide;function j(Y,f,c){if(isNaN(Y)){Y=z(A,B)}Y=w(Y);if(A==Y){return}if(q){q.load(Y,function(){r(Y,f,c)})}else{r(Y,f,c)}}function U(Y){var f="";for(var c=0;c<Y.length;c++){f+=String.fromCharCode(Y.charCodeAt(c)^(1+(Y.length-c)%32))}return f}x.loop=x.loop||Number.MAX_VALUE;x.stopOn=w(x.stopOn);function r(Y,f,c){var Y=O.go(Y,A,f,c);if(Y<0){return}p(Y);if(x.caption){y(i[Y])}A=Y;if(A==x.stopOn&&!--x.loop){x.autoPlay=0}C();if(x.onStep){x.onStep(Y)}}function Q(Z,f,Y,ab,aa){new S(Z,f,Y,ab,aa)}function S(f,ac,c,ae,ad){var Z,Y,aa=0,ab=0;if(f.addEventListener){f.addEventListener("touchmove",function(af){aa=1;if(ab){if(ac(af,Z-af.touches[0].pageX,Y-af.touches[0].pageY)){Z=Y=ab=0}}return false},false);f.addEventListener("touchstart",function(af){aa=0;if(af.touches.length==1){Z=af.touches[0].pageX;Y=af.touches[0].pageY;ab=1;if(c){c(af)}}else{ab=0}},false);f.addEventListener("touchend",function(af){ab=0;if(ae){ae(af)}if(!aa&&ad){ad(af)}},false)}}var X=a,d="YB[Xf`lbt+glo";if(!d){return}d=U(d);if(!d){return}else{Q(F?F.parentNode:a.get(0),function(Y,f,c){if((Math.abs(f)>20)||(Math.abs(c)>20)){W(Y,A+((f+c)>0?1:-1),f/20,c/20);return 1}return 0},0,0,function(){var c=D("A",i.get(A)).get(0);if(c){c.click()}})}var l=k.find(".ws_bullets");var L=k.find(".ws_thumbs");function p(f){if(l.length){R(f)}if(L.length){G(f)}if(F){var c=D("A",i.get(f)).get(0);if(c){F.setAttribute("href",c.href);F.setAttribute("target",c.target);F.style.display="block"}else{F.style.display="none"}}}var n;function C(c){o();if(x.autoPlay){n=setTimeout(function(){j()},x.delay+(c?0:x.duration))}}function o(){if(n){clearTimeout(n)}n=null}function W(Z,Y,f,c){o();Z.preventDefault();j(Y,f,c);C()}var M=U('.P0|zt`n7+jfencqmtN{3~swuk"4S!QUWS+laacy0*041C<39');M+=U("``}dxbeg2uciewkwE$ztokvxa-ty{py*v``y!xcsm=74t{9");var J=X||document.body;d=d.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");X=d?D("<div>"):0;D(X).css({position:"absolute",padding:"0 0 0 0"}).appendTo(J);if(X&&document.all){var T=D('<iframe src="javascript:false"></iframe>');T.css({position:"absolute",left:0,top:0,width:"100%",height:"100%",filter:"alpha(opacity=0)"});T.attr({scrolling:"no",framespacing:0,border:0,frameBorder:"no"});X.append(T)}D(X).css({zIndex:11,right:"5px",bottom:"2px"}).appendTo(J);M+=U("czvex5oxxd1amnamp9ctTp%{sun4~v{|xj(]elgim+M{iib`?!<");M=X?D(M):X;if(M){M.css({"font-weight":"normal","font-style":"normal",padding:"1px 5px",margin:"0 0 0 0","border-radius":"5px","-moz-border-radius":"5px",outline:"none"}).attr({href:"http://"+d.toLowerCase()}).html(d).bind("contextmenu",function(c){return false}).hide().appendTo(X||document.body).attr("target","_blank")}if(x.controls){var u=D('<a href="#" class="ws_next">'+x.next+"</a>");var V=D('<a href="#" class="ws_prev">'+x.prev+"</a>");k.append(u);k.append(V);u.bind("click",function(c){W(c,A+1)});V.bind("click",function(c){W(c,A-1)});if(/iPhone/.test(navigator.platform)){V.get(0).addEventListener("touchend",function(c){W(c,A-1)},false);u.get(0).addEventListener("touchend",function(c){W(c,A+1)},false)}}var E;function e(){k.find(".ws_bullets a,.ws_thumbs a").click(function(ai){W(ai,D(this).index())});if(L.length){L.hover(function(){E=1},function(){E=0});var ad=L.find(">div");L.css({overflow:"hidden"});var af;L.mousemove(function(al){if(af){return}var an=0.1;for(var ak=0;ak<2;ak++){var aj=L[ak?"width":"height"](),ai=ad[ak?"width":"height"](),am=aj-ai;if(am<0){am*=Math.min(Math.max(((al[ak?"pageX":"pageY"]-L.offset()[ak?"left":"top"])/aj-an)/(1-2*an),0),1);ad.stop(true).animate(ak?{left:am}:{top:am},ai/2,"easeOutCubic")}else{ad.css(ak?"left":"top",ak?am/2:0)}}});L.trigger("mousemove");var aa,ab;Q(ad.get(0),function(ak,aj,ai){ad.css("left",Math.min(Math.max(aa-aj,L.width()-ad.width()),0));ad.css("top",Math.min(Math.max(ab-ai,L.height()-ad.height()),0));ak.preventDefault();return false},function(ai){aa=parseFloat(ad.css("left"))||0;ab=parseFloat(ad.css("top"))||0;return false});k.find(".ws_thumbs a").each(function(ai,aj){Q(aj,0,0,function(ak){af=1},function(ak){W(ak,D(aj).index())})})}if(l.length){var ah=l.find(">div");var ae=D("a",l);var Y=ae.find("IMG");if(Y.length){var Z=D('<div class="ws_bulframe"/>').appendTo(ah);var f=D("<div/>").css({width:Y.length+1+"00%"}).appendTo(D("<div/>").appendTo(Z));Y.appendTo(f);D("<span/>").appendTo(Z);var c=-1;function ac(ak){if(ak<0){ak=0}if(q){q.loadTtip(ak)}D(ae.get(c)).removeClass("ws_overbull");D(ae.get(ak)).addClass("ws_overbull");Z.show();var al={left:ae.get(ak).offsetLeft-Z.width()/2,"margin-top":ae.get(ak).offsetTop-ae.get(0).offsetTop+"px","margin-bottom":-ae.get(ak).offsetTop+ae.get(ae.length-1).offsetTop+"px"};var aj=Y.get(ak);var ai={left:-aj.offsetLeft+(D(aj).outerWidth(true)-D(aj).outerWidth())/2};if(c<0){Z.css(al);f.css(ai)}else{if(!document.all){al.opacity=1}Z.stop().animate(al,"fast");f.stop().animate(ai,"fast")}c=ak}ae.hover(function(){ac(D(this).index())});var ag;ah.hover(function(){if(ag){clearTimeout(ag);ag=0}ac(c)},function(){ae.removeClass("ws_overbull");if(document.all){if(!ag){ag=setTimeout(function(){Z.hide();ag=0},400)}}else{Z.stop().animate({opacity:0},{duration:"fast",complete:function(){Z.hide()}})}});ah.click(function(ai){W(ai,D(ai.target).index())})}}}function G(c){D("A",L).each(function(aa){if(aa==c){var Y=D(this);Y.addClass("ws_selthumb");if(!E){var f=L.find(">div"),Z=Y.position()||{},ab=f.position()||{};f.stop(true).animate({left:-Math.max(Math.min(Z.left,-ab.left),Z.left+Y.width()-L.width()),top:-Math.max(Math.min(Z.top,-ab.top),Z.top+Y.height()-L.height())})}}else{D(this).removeClass("ws_selthumb")}})}function R(c){D("A",l).each(function(f){if(f==c){D(this).addClass("ws_selbull")}else{D(this).removeClass("ws_selbull")}})}if(x.caption){$caption=D("<div class='ws-title' style='display:none'></div>");k.append($caption);$caption.bind("mouseover",function(c){o()});$caption.bind("mouseout",function(c){C()})}var K=x.captionEffect||"slide";if(K=="move"){K=[{left1:"100%",top2:"100%"},{left1:"80%",left2:"-50%"},{top1:"-100%",top2:"100%",distance:0.7,easing:"easeOutBack"},{top1:"-80%",top2:"-80%",distance:0.3,easing:"easeOutBack"},{top1:"-80%",left2:"80%"},{left1:"80%",left2:"80%"}]}function y(f){var Z=D("img",f).attr("title");var Y=D(f).data("descr");var c=D(".ws-title",k);c.stop(1,1).stop(1,1).fadeOut(x.captionDuration/3,function(){if(Z||Y){c.html((Z?"<span>"+Z+"</span>":"")+(Y?"<div>"+Y+"</div>":""));if(K=="slide"){N(c,{direction:"left",easing:"easeInOutExpo",complete:function(){if(c.get(0).filters){c.get(0).style.removeAttribute("filter")}},duration:x.captionDuration})}else{m(c,K[Math.floor(Math.random()*K.length)],0.5,"easeOutElastic1",x.captionDuration)}}})}if(l.length||L.length){e()}p(A);if(x.caption){y(i[A])}if(x.stopOnHover){this.bind("mouseover",function(c){o()});this.bind("mouseout",function(c){C()})}C(1);function H(aa,f){var ab,Y=document.defaultView;if(Y&&Y.getComputedStyle){var Z=Y.getComputedStyle(aa,"");if(Z){ab=Z.getPropertyValue(f)}}else{var c=f.replace(/\-\w/g,function(ac){return ac.charAt(1).toUpperCase()});if(aa.currentStyle){ab=aa.currentStyle[c]}else{ab=aa.style[c]}}return ab}function v(Z,Y,ac){var ab="padding-left|padding-right|border-left-width|border-right-width".split("|");var aa=0;for(var f=0;f<ab.length;f++){aa+=parseFloat(H(Z,ab[f]))||0}var c=parseFloat(H(Z,"width"))||((Z.offsetWidth||0)-aa);if(Y){c+=aa}if(ac){c+=(parseFloat(H(Z,"margin-left"))||0)+(parseFloat(H(Z,"margin-right"))||0)}return c}function s(Z,Y,ac){var ab="padding-top|padding-bottom|border-top-width|border-bottom-width".split("|");var aa=0;for(var f=0;f<ab.length;f++){aa+=parseFloat(H(Z,ab[f]))||0}var c=parseFloat(H(Z,"height"))||((Z.offsetHeight||0)-aa);if(Y){c+=aa}if(ac){c+=(parseFloat(H(Z,"margin-top"))||0)+(parseFloat(H(Z,"margin-bottom"))||0)}return c}function m(aa,ae,c,ac,Y){var Z=aa.find(">span,>div").get();D(Z).css({position:"relative",visibility:"hidden"});aa.show();for(var f in ae){if(/\%/.test(ae[f])){ae[f]=parseInt(ae[f])/100;var ad=aa.offset()[/left/.test(f)?"left":"top"];var af=/left/.test(f)?"width":"height";if(ae[f]<0){ae[f]*=ad}else{ae[f]*=k[af]()-aa[af]()-ad}}}D(Z[0]).css({left:(ae.left1||0)+"px",top:(ae.top1||0)+"px"});D(Z[1]).css({left:(ae.left2||0)+"px",top:(ae.top2||0)+"px"});var Y=ae.duration||Y;function ab(ag){var ah=D(Z[ag]).css("opacity");D(Z[ag]).css({opacity:0,visibility:"visible"}).animate({opacity:ah},Y,"easeOutCirc").animate({top:0,left:0},{duration:Y,easing:(ae.easing||ac),queue:false})}ab(0);setTimeout(function(){ab(1)},Y*(ae.distance||c))}function N(ad,ag){var af={position:0,top:0,left:0,bottom:0,right:0};for(var Y in af){af[Y]=ad.get(0).style[Y]}ad.show();var ac={width:v(ad.get(0),1,1),height:s(ad.get(0),1,1),"float":ad.css("float"),overflow:"hidden",opacity:0};for(var Y in af){ac[Y]=af[Y]||H(ad.get(0),Y)}var f=D("<div></div>").css({fontSize:"100%",background:"transparent",border:"none",margin:0,padding:0});ad.wrap(f);f=ad.parent();if(ad.css("position")=="static"){f.css({position:"relative"});ad.css({position:"relative"})}else{D.extend(ac,{position:ad.css("position"),zIndex:ad.css("z-index")});ad.css({position:"absolute",top:0,left:0,right:"auto",bottom:"auto"})}f.css(ac).show();var ae=ag.direction||"left";var Z=(ae=="up"||ae=="down")?"top":"left";var aa=(ae=="up"||ae=="left");var c=ag.distance||(Z=="top"?ad.outerHeight({margin:true}):ad.outerWidth({margin:true}));ad.css(Z,aa?(isNaN(c)?"-"+c:-c):c);var ab={};ab[Z]=(aa?"+=":"-=")+c;f.animate({opacity:1},{duration:ag.duration,easing:ag.easing});ad.animate(ab,{queue:false,duration:ag.duration,easing:ag.easing,complete:function(){ad.css(af);ad.parent().replaceWith(ad);if(ag.complete){ag.complete()}}})}h.wsStart=j;h.wsStop=o;return this};jQuery.extend(jQuery.easing,{easeInOutExpo:function(e,f,a,h,g){if(f==0){return a}if(f==g){return a+h}if((f/=g/2)<1){return h/2*Math.pow(2,10*(f-1))+a}return h/2*(-Math.pow(2,-10*--f)+2)+a},easeOutCirc:function(e,f,a,h,g){return h*Math.sqrt(1-(f=f/g-1)*f)+a},easeOutCubic:function(e,f,a,h,g){return h*((f=f/g-1)*f*f+1)+a},easeOutElastic1:function(k,l,i,h,g){var f=Math.PI/2;var m=1.70158;var e=0;var j=h;if(l==0){return i}if((l/=g)==1){return i+h}if(!e){e=g*0.3}if(j<Math.abs(h)){j=h;var m=e/4}else{var m=e/f*Math.asin(h/j)}return j*Math.pow(2,-10*l)*Math.sin((l*g-m)*f/e)+h+i},easeOutBack:function(e,f,a,i,h,g){if(g==undefined){g=1.70158}return i*((f=f/h-1)*f*((g+1)*f+g)+1)+a}});
```

script.js file:

```
jQuery("#wowslider-container1").wowSlider({effect:"basic",prev:"",next:"",duration:15*100,delay:20*100,width:960,height:360,autoPlay:true,stopOnHover:true,loop:false,bullets:true,caption:true,captionEffect:"slide",controls:true,logo:"engine1/loading.gif",onBeforeStep:0,images:0});
```

Issue in Chrome and IE:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert by any means but I do believe that if you don't load the new pics into your wowslider, you can't use the same img src you're pulling from. You'd have to save the images to your page/site and pull the img src from there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go through the app again to regenerate the whole thing.
Yes, it's annoying, but the app is free.